# how to reroute black sewer pipe

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sewer

edit 12/30/2019: 
- adding a picture of the vent stack above the subfloor and to the right a sink drain that has it's own vent that ties in
- there is a red plug in the T. where the trap from the shower drain will connect. This was a tub being converted to a shower with a tile floor, hence the desire to reinforce the subfloor

I need to drop the bathroom subfloor level to the tops of the joists by sistering joists onto the existing joists dropped by 3/4". The black cast iron sewer pipe in this picture has a threaded T that you can't see, but is interconnected with no-hub couplings right now and is capped with threaded steel pipe and a pipe cap. All of this is fine, but I want to drop it down about an inch to put in a plywood subfloor.

My thoughts are to convert that whole section to black ABS sewer pipe, assuming that the process may allow me to drop that T down the inch that I need. Before I hit the pipe fitting aisle at home depot, I thought I would run it by here and see if anyone had any ideas about this. thx

[image]

[image]

Comment: is that a vent stack on the left?

Comment: That's my guess.  I just re-read the post.  He says it's a vent.

Comment: I don't see what purpose the T, with the removable plug in it serves.  That's looks like something used to pressure test the lines after construction.  It's not accessible once the floor is put down.

Comment: I updated some details at the top of the original post!